# 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I run this:

> 

```
!python models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py
 --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_training_steps=200
```

and get this error: tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v2

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
        tf.compat.v1.app.run()   File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.7/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
        _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
        _run_main(main, args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in
    _run_main
        sys.exit(main(argv))   File "models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 101, in main
        strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()   File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.7/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
        attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name) AttributeError: module '**tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2.compat' has no attribute 'v2**'
```

I also use this for API:

```
 %tensorflow_version 1.x
import os
import pathlib

# Clone the tensorflow models repository if it doesn't already exist
if "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
  while "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
    os.chdir('..')
elif not pathlib.Path('models').exists():
  !git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/cloud-annotations/models

!pip install cloud-annotations==0.0.4
!pip install tf_slim
!pip install lvis
!pip install --no-deps tensorflowjs==1.4.0

%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Object_Detecation/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

pwd = os.getcwd()
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += f':{pwd}:{pwd}/slim'

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

Can anyone help about it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `compat.v2` API, but you are trying to run code in `Tensorflowv 1.x`.

Replace

```
strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```

With

```
tf.compat.v1.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```